# pytorch classifier for mnist data not work

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm new to pytorch, and I try to train a simple classifier with mnist data. However, my classifier's accuracy is about 10%, I tried several method to adjust the network, but failed, the classifier's output label is always the same, all 0, or all 7, or all 6. Please tell me what is wrong with the code.(I know I should use DataLoader, I will take a look at it later, now I just want to make the classifier's accuracy looks gook)

```
# coding=utf-8
# 数据为data中的handwritten_digit

import struct
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import time

data_folder = '../data/handwritten_digit/'
dt = torch.get_default_dtype()
train_label_file = 'train-labels-idx1-ubyte'
train_img_file = 'train-images-idx3-ubyte'
test_img_file = 't10k-images-idx3-ubyte'
test_label_file = 't10k-labels-idx1-ubyte'
model_path = './handwritten_digit_recognition_net3.pth'

def timer(func):
    def cal_time(*args, **kw):
        start_time = time.time()
        out = func(*args, **kw)
        end_time = time.time()
        print('函数 ', func.__name__, ' 运行耗时', end_time-start_time, '秒', sep = '')
        return out
    return cal_time

def read_imgs(file):
    with open(data_folder+file, 'rb') as frb:
        # 先读取meta
        magic_num, img_num, row_num, col_num = struct.unpack('>IIII', frb.read(16))
        # print(magic_num, img_num, row_num, col_num)
        # img = np.fromfile(frb, dtype = np.uint8, count = row_num*col_num).reshape(row_num, col_num)
        # print(img, img.shape, 'img')
        imgs = np.fromfile(frb, dtype = np.uint8).reshape(img_num, row_num, col_num)
        # imgs = np.fromfile(frb, dtype = np.uint8, count = row_num*col_num*img_num).reshape(img_num, row_num, col_num)
    return torch.from_numpy(imgs).type(dt).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(1)

def read_labels(file):
    with open(data_folder+file, 'rb') as frb:
        # 先读取meta
        magic_num, label_num = struct.unpack('>II', frb.read(8))
        # print(magic_num, label_num)
        labels = np.fromfile(frb, dtype = np.uint8)
    return torch.from_numpy(labels).type(dt)

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 12, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(12, 12, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(12*16, 30)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(30, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 12*16)
        # print(x.size(), 'x.size()')
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = self.linear2(x)
        return x



@timer
def train_and_save_net():
    train_imgs = read_imgs(train_img_file)
    train_labels = read_labels(train_label_file)
    test_imgs = read_imgs(test_img_file)
    test_labels = read_labels(test_label_file)

    # label = torch.zeros(1, 10)

    # label[0][int(train_labels[0])] = 1
    # print(label)
    # print(train_labels[0])
    # return

    net = Net()
    # criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr = 0.001, momentum = 0.9)

    print('Start Training')
    sum_loss = 0
    for i, img in enumerate(train_imgs):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        predicted = net(img)
        # label = torch.zeros(1, 10)
        # label[0][int(train_labels[i])] = 1
        label = torch.tensor([train_labels[i]], dtype = torch.long)
        # print(predicted, predicted.size(), 'predicted')
        # print(label, label.size(), 'label')
        loss = criterion(predicted, label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        sum_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 2000 == 1999:
            print('已经训练了', i+1, '张图片，', '完成进度：', '%.2f'%((i+1)/len(train_labels)*100), '%', sep = '')
            print('loss为：', sum_loss/2000)
            sum_loss = 0
    print('End Training')

    torch.save(net.state_dict(), model_path)
    print('End Saving Net Parameters')


def load_net():
    net = Net()
    net.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))
    return net

@timer
def evaluate():

    train_imgs = read_imgs(train_img_file)
    train_labels = read_labels(train_label_file)
    test_imgs = read_imgs(test_img_file)
    test_labels = read_labels(test_label_file)

    net = load_net()

    # 直观感受
    for i in range(5):
        img = train_imgs[i]
        # plt.imshow(img.squeeze(), cmap = 'gray')
        # plt.show()
        predicted_vector = net(img)
        _, predicted = torch.max(predicted_vector, 1)
        predicted = predicted.item()
        print('预测的分类是：', predicted, '，实际的分类是：', int(train_labels[i].item()), sep = '')

    # 训练集精度
    total = len(train_labels)
    correct = 0
    for i in range(len(train_labels)):
        img = train_imgs[i]
        predicted_vector = net(img)
        _, predicted = torch.max(predicted_vector, 1)
        label = int(train_labels[i].item())
        if predicted == label:
            correct += 1
    print('训练集上的准确率为：', '%.2f'%(correct/total*100), '%', sep = '')


    total = len(test_labels)
    correct = 0
    pre_arr = []
    for i in range(len(test_labels)):
        img = test_imgs[i]
        predicted_vector = net(img)
        _, predicted = torch.max(predicted_vector, 1)
        label = int(test_labels[i].item())
        pre_arr.append(predicted)
        if predicted == label:
            correct += 1
    print('测试集上的准确率为：', '%.2f'%(correct/total*100), '%', sep = '')
    print('模型判断为0的个数/总判断数 为：', pre_arr.count(0), '/', len(pre_arr), sep = '')

@timer
def test():
    predicted_vector = torch.randn(1,10)
    _, predicted = torch.max(predicted_vector, 1)
    print(predicted.item())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_and_save_net()
    # test()
    evaluate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I seem to figure out where the problem is, I changed the learning rate from 1e-3 to 1e-4, then the accuracy reached about 97%...